# Simple query on linq

Tags: c#, linq

using linq, I want to check if a row exist on the DB. I just need a true\false return, no data.
I cant use the ExecuteQuery method because I dont have an entity (and I dont even need it)
I thought of doing something like this:

```
string command = "select * from myTable where X=Y"
var result = db.ExecuteCommand(command);
```

(db is my DataContext)
and expected the result to contain the number of affected rows. If different that -1 it would mean the record I'm looking for exists. But I always get -1. I imagine the ExecuteCommand method should only be used to tu run Insert, updates or deletes.

How can I run this simple check using linq

Comment: Is there a reason to not use a normal linq query with the `Any()` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `db` is your data context, you should just do:

```
bool rowExists = dc.GetTable<myTable>().Any(row => row.X == row.Y);
```

In general, with LINQ to SQL (and Entity Framework), you rarely want to write SQL code directly.

Comment: cool it does work. There is one detail, though. Y is comming from the app as a name and I need ID. That's why I was thinking on writing a query because Y would be something like (select ID from tableY where name = 'name_from_app'). I hardcoded this ID to test your solution but of course I cant do that. Oh and this second table is on a different dataContext (because its a different database) so I dont think I can use on the same query. What do you suggest other than getting the value of Y on a first query and then use it on the second as I hard-coded it?
Thanks

Comment: @Diego You can have a variable, ie: `string foo = "Test";  bool exist = dc.GetTable<myTable>().Any(row => row.Name = foo);`  If you're working from two separate databases, you'll have to get the name from one in a query, then pass the name to the other (you can't do cross-database joins)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Any()` operator.  It will return true if the `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` it is called on has at least one item (i.e. does it have *any* items).

Comment: To clarify, will that actually grab all the records from the database and then count them in .NET, or will it just grab the count from the database? I would have suggested that, but I wasn't sure if it would reduce the efficiency of the code by loading all the records into memory!

Comment: @ekolis That will depend on the specific database provider that you're using, but most of them should be able to translate `Any` into a query that determines the number of rows at the database, rather than returning the rows and doing the check in .NET.  Of course, if you have an `IEnumerable`, rather than an `IQueryable` it can only perform the check in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
select *
```

with

```
select count(*)
```

Comment: That's odd... the count function shouldn't be returning negative numbers, unless maybe there's an error or something!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off running `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE X=Y` and checking if the single record returned is equal to zero or not

Comment: @ReedCopsey Well, he would need to convert the rest of the query into Linq first.  If he doesn't, then you can't use `Any`.

Comment: Since he seemed to want to use SQL directly, I chose to address that first.